# Sending request to instagram with Authorization Token/Cookie from Postman

Tags: request, postman, instagram, instaloader

I want to get some story datas. After a few search on internet I found an endpoint like that:

https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_media/?reel_ids=

But when I send a request to the endpoint I get an response like that:

> {"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}

After that, I added user-agent and I tried to send test request from Postman,

So, My request like that:

[image: Postman Request Screen Shot]

But Response like that:

[image: Postman Response Screen Shot]

So, How Can I send this request from Postman successfully? Please Help!